# What is the name of this berry producing tree?

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

I live in Middle Tennessee (USA) and came across [this tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyzRK.jpg) while I was hiking through the woods. I'm curious as to what type of tree this is and if the berries have any uses or are poisonous.

The tree is rather short, and I was unable to see any more distinctive features given that the tree was surrounded by other brush. I can supply a better picture in a day or two if necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is some type of Sumac in the genus Rhus. Probably either *Rhus glabra* (Smooth Sumac) or *Rhus typhina* (Staghorn Sumac). The berries of those two species are supposedly not poisonous. But they are closely related to other poisonous plants such as poison ivy and poison sumac. Poison ivy and poison sumac are in the genus Toxicodendron, but used to be in the genus Rhus.

A photo of Smooth Sumac
[image: Rhus glabra]